# Sink basin gasket leaking

Tags: plumbing, sink, plumbing-fixture, caulking, kitchen-sink

I've got a sink basin installed under granite that looks kindof like this:

[image]

All around the outside of the sink sandwiched between the basin and the granite is a rubber gasket that has started to fail (break apart and deteriorate) in some areas. I'm handy enough to remove the basin and put a new gasket around it (which I assume is custom and came with the sink but I could probably figure something out), however I am afraid of causing more problems - namely, that the granite might crack from the stress.

Is it ok for me to caulk with clear silicon around the basin? Or should the sink really be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "fail" you just mean crack, deteriorate, or otherwise fall apart, just caulking will be fine. The gasket was probably a time-saver that came with the sink, but typical undermount installations just use caulk to seal the gap.

Trying to remove and replace the whole sink is a real project -- they're glued and clipped to the counter. I replaced my undermount sink, which looked much like yours, with a single-basin granite undermount... it took a full day and plenty of cursing.

Comment: Yea its falling apart and the rubber is sort of looking a bit like an old windshield wiper. Yea that is indeed what I was thinking regarding taking the sink out. Caulk it is!